# Не получается получить HashMap на контроллер в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Так заполняю Map и отправляю на jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addProductView(@RequestParam("categoryId") int categoryId, ModelMap model) {
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //здесь просто заполняю ключами из базы
    for (Attribute attribute: productService.getCategoryByKey(categoryId).getAttributes()){
        attributes.put(attribute.getAttributeName(), null);
    }

    model.addAttribute("attributes", attributes);
    model.addAttribute("attributeSize", attributes.size() - 1);
    return "addProduct";
}
```

Так получаю

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProduct(HashMap<String,String> attributes, ModelMap model) {
    System.err.println(attributes.size());
    return "admin";
}
```

И сама jsp

```
<spring:form action="/addNewProduct" method="post" class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="attributes">
                    <c:forEach items="${attributes}" var="attributes" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            <label class="input-group-addon">${attributes.key}
                                <spring:input path="attributes['${attributes.key}']" class="form-control"
                                       value="${attributes.value}"/>
                            </label>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Save"/>
                </div>
            </spring:form>
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Табличка на странице получается пустая? Или `attributes.size()` в обработчике POST возвращает 0?

Comment: attributes.size() равен 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, не стоит в теге `c:forEach` атрибуту `var` давать такое же значение, какое содержится в атрибуте `items`. Во-вторых, если вы посмотрите html-код сформированной страницы, то поймёте, что тег `spring:input` портит значение атрибута `path`, убирая квадратные скобки. Происходит это потому, что согласно стандарту html атрибут `name` не может содержать квадратные скобки. И потому, что атрибут `path` предназначен для указания поля модели в точечной нотации, а не доступа к элементам коллекции по индексу. Наконец, Map стоит завернуть в класс модели:

**form.jsp** (View)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="nameForm">
            <c:forEach items="${nameForm.nameMap}" var="item">
                <label>${item.key}</label>
                <input type="text" name="nameMap['${item.key}']" value="${item.value}">
                <br>
            </c:forEach>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NameForm.java** (Model)

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NameForm {
    private Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();

    public NameForm() {}

    public NameForm(Map<String, String> nameMap) {
        this.nameMap = nameMap;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getNameMap() {
        return nameMap;
    }

    public void setNameMap(Map<String, String> nameMap) {
        this.nameMap = nameMap;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return String.join(" ", nameMap.values());
    }
}
```

**FormController.java** (Controller)

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FormController {
    private static Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        nameMap.put("firstname", "Аноним");
        nameMap.put("lastname", "Анонимов");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        NameForm nameForm = new NameForm(nameMap);
        return new ModelAndView("form" , "nameForm", nameForm);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleForm(@ModelAttribute("nameForm") NameForm nameForm) {
        System.out.println(nameForm.getFullName());
        return new ModelAndView("form", "nameForm", nameForm);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем Map оборачивать в класс?